# Which is better : using $("#myVar") directly or saving it to a variable first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and I'd like to know whether it is good practice to save $("#myVar") to a variable first like this

```
var jQvar = $("#myVar");
```

or directly using it like this:

```
var myVar = $("#myVar").val();
$("#myVar").removeProp("disabled");
..
```

and when is the best time to use the other  over the other? (var and NonVar)

Comment: When you look up something in a book. Do you find the page, read a sentence and close it. Open the book up to that page same exact page  to find something else? That is basically what you are doing when you do not save the page, you keep having to find it. That time adds up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time you are accessing an element it takes (little but still) time. So saving it to a variable makes sense in terms of performance and efficiency if you access the element more then once in the current scope.

So writing it like this:

```
var myVar = $("#myVar");
var myVal = myVar.val();
myVar.removeProp("disabled");
```

will be faster.

In your specific case, this is the difference for me:

[image]

<kbd>[Try for your self](http://jsperf.com/var-vs-novarttt)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And thank you also for introducing jsPerf (JavaScript performance playground) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var jQvar = $("#myVar");
 - jQvar.val();
 - jQvar.onclick(function(){
// do something here
});

 - jQvar.onSubmit(function(){
// do something here
});
```

... obviously this is more faster, you can reduce redundancy of variable declaration, much neater and less clutter you don't want to scroll and find every variable in file right?